# if clicked 1+2 button true or wrong.How I do that

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

A few fish come to the screen and stop after a while the other fishes come in.Then a while the stage is stopped and the player is trying to guess the first fishes.How can I create code to say that the chosen fish is wrong or true.For example:The first come 3 fishes it's correct and after then came fishes wrong.Player guess right all the fishes and earn coins or display win text bla bla..

I selected to sequence of the fish at timeline.So yes I animated.I was using as3 random function for the display on the screen.

This is a memory game.Fishes (it's buttons ) display on the screen and stop then other fishes ( a wrong fishes ) display.After a while stops all the scene and player choose ( click ) right fishes.So all I need: if clicked button 1 + button2  = true then go to bla bla. if wrong goto bla bla. All in the one order...I don't put code for display to fish,just I put here a button code .

```
fish1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click1);
fish2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click2);
fish3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click3);
fish4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click4);
fish5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click5);
var PC:Boolean = false;
 
function click1 ( m:MouseEvent ){
PC = true;
}
 
function click2 ( m:MouseEvent ){
PC = true;
}
 
function click3 ( m:MouseEvent ){
PC = true;
}
 
function click4 ( m:MouseEvent ){
PC = true;
}
 
function click5 ( m:MouseEvent ){
if ( PC ) 
{
 
PC = false;
gotoAndPlay (1);
}
}
```

Comment: Even after reading this new post I still think my answer to your last post is the way to go. Was there something about my answer you didn't understand or that won't work for you?

Comment: Basically each time a choice is made by the player increment your array position up by one. You should be traversing an array. This is pretty standard password checking algorithm. Go back to my answer on your last post and focus on making that work. It's a good answer. If you don't understand something about it ask.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. So you know how many fishes are CORRECT right  , so use

```
//number of correct fishes
var correctFishesCount:int = 3;

//add a number to this temporary count to check whether user predicted all fishes
var userCount:int = 0;

fish1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click1);
fish2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click2);
fish3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click3);
fish4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click4);
fish5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click5);
var PC:Boolean = false;

function addUserCount(){
userCount++;
if(userCount == correctFishesCount)
     We Have a winner
}

function click1 ( m:MouseEvent ){
PC = true;
addUserCount()
}

function click2 ( m:MouseEvent ){
PC = true;
addUserCount()
}

function click3 ( m:MouseEvent ){
PC = true;
addUserCount()
}

function click4 ( m:MouseEvent ){
PC = true;
addUserCount()
}

    function click5 ( m:MouseEvent ){
if ( PC ) 
{
PC = false;
gotoAndPlay (1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks jeffin but I have another problem.I want to display result after when player has choice true or wrong 3  fishes.What problem is here,we know fish 5 it's wrong but when I clicked fish5 first and then choice another it's not work.

Its work when I click twice on the fish5.Problem is here.
Click = Some fish + Fish5 it's okay
Click = Fish5 + Some fish it's not work.
Click = Fish5 + Some fish + Fish 5 again. This is work,but shouldn't work like this.

Comment: Also didn't work true function to.I was clicked true fishes but nothing happened.